# Yahoo Stock API ticker trend function

Tags: api, yahoo-finance

Can anyone give any insight to what Yahoo returns for this call?

The reference is t7 ticker trend.

When submitting a symbol for this function, yahoo responds with something similar to the following:

```
AAPL nbsp;==+-+==nbsp;
```

I have scoured the interwebs to find an explanation of this output, but have come up empty handed.

Anyone have any experience with this call?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AAPL - the stock ticker
&nbsp; - a space placed at the beginning and the end of the trend
==+-+== - the ticker trend. It's made up of three components

= :  the price paid is the same as before
+ :  the price paid is greater than the trade before
- :  the price paid is less than the trade before. 

So say a stock trades at $1.00.  The next trade is for $1.01 which is an increase 
and so the ticker trend would show +.  The next two trades are at $1.01 so they 
would display as == since there was no change in price.  The stock then trades at 
$1.00, then $.99, then $.98 so it would show ---.  The complete ticker trend would 
show +==---

The usefulness of this is to show trends. If the stock shows  +++++ then that's a pretty clear indication that people are lined up and each one is willing to pay more than the last. Something is probably going on with that stock. ===== would show that the market is very confident in the price of the stock. +==-+-  would be a bit of a mixed bag, not giving any clear signal of what the market thinks of the stock.